# java.lang.AssertionError: Range for response status value 404 expected:<SUCCESSFUL> but was:<CLIENT_ERROR>

Tags: spring-boot, junit

** Please help me to find the reason for the error java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<404>.I tried to implement MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON Annotation @EnableWebMvc. But not working. I am not able to use mockMcv to hit the GET call. Added code for the controller and test controller with pom.xml. 
//STS logs : main] WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping for GET /availabile/SL/details**

````
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId> 
    <scope>test</scope> 
</dependency> 
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId> 
    <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId> 
    <scope>text</scope> 
</dependency>

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SuiteClasses({AvController.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class AvControllerTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private AvController avController;

    @Mock
    private Processor processor;
    @Mock
    private YService yService;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Mock
    private UYaml uYaml;
    private Map<String, String> expected = null;
    private static final String contract_Base_Uri = "/available";

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); 
        uYaml = new UYaml();
        expected = new HashMap<String, String>();// expected has mock data
        uYaml.setData(data);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(avController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetDetails_returnCorrectHttpStatus() throws Exception {
    when(processor.getYaml()).thenReturn(uYaml);

        assertFalse(processor.isYMLBlank(uYaml));

        when(processor.isYMLBlank(uYaml)).thenReturn(true);// not blank
        when(processor.getYaml()).thenReturn(uYaml);
        when(yService.getHDetails(uYaml)).thenReturn(expected);

        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(get(contract_Base_Uri+"/SL/details"))
                .andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful());

        String content = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();
        System.out.println("Result JSON : " + content);
    }

ControllerClass :

    @RestController
    @EnableWebMvc
    @ComponentScan
    @RequestMapping("/available")
    public class AvailabilityController {

    @Autowired
    private Processor processor;
    @Autowired
    private YService yService;

    @GetMapping(path = "/SL/details")
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>> getDetails() {

        if (null == uYaml)
            uYaml = processor.getYaml();

        Map<String, String> map = yService.getHDetails(uYaml);

        if (null != map && map.size() > 0)
            return new ResponseEntity<>(map, HttpStatus.OK);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);        
    }

    @Test
    public void testDependencyAllCheck() {
        assertNotNull(mockMvc);
    }

ErrorMessage : 

java.lang.AssertionError: Range for response status value 404 expected:<SUCCESSFUL> but was:<CLIENT_ERROR>
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:59)
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:122)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers.lambda$is2xxSuccessful$3(StatusResultMatchers.java:78)...```
````

Comment: because of this line - `return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);` it returns 404

Comment: Solution: Silly mistake. Done!!! I was passing false instead of true in. Thank you, Hemant...